# Qual è il significato di "tosto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La resurrezione di Lazzaro* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Ah, guarda, quello è Gesú... quello piccolo... Come è giovane... guarda, non ha neanche la barba... com'è delicato... pare un ragazzino. Io me lo immaginavo piú **tosto**, con una gran testa di capelli... con delle pallettone (*indica le orecchie*), una crestona tremenda, con dei denti, 
>   delle manone, che quando cominciava a benedire: 
>   PAA!... troncava in quattro i fedeli! Che giovane che è!...

Ho cercato il vocabolo "tosto" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le differenti accezioni che ho trovato, non so a quale corrisponde l'uso che si fa nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DIrei che in questa frase ***tosto*** significa *risoluto ed energico*, in contrapposizione alla figura imberbe e delicata che sorprende il personaggio che sta parlando.

Un altro significato, più negativo, dell'aggettivo ***tosto*** rivolto a persone è *testardo, ostinato,* ma non mi pare la giusta interpretazione in questo contesto.

Comment: Corrisponde all'ultima accezione riportata dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tosto1): “Nel linguaggio fam., riferito anche a persona, con il sign. di ostinato, testardo, che non cede facilmente, come valutazione non necessariamente negativa, anzi spesso associata a un giudizio di energia e risolutezza: *è un tipo t., che non cede e non si scoraggia alla prima difficoltà*”.

Comment: Grazie per il riferimento autorevole, vedo che il Treccani raggruppa i due significati che io percepisco come differenti, probabilmente la distinzione è solo nella mia testa.

Answer (score 2):

Anch'io direi che qui "tosto" è da collegarsi all'aspetto virile e forte che può dare una barba folta. Nel periodo prima, infatti, fa intendere che non avendo la barba è "delicato"

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!