# Esiste un proverbio italiano equivalente a quello inglese che dice “happy wife, happy life”?

Tags: proverbs

Come evidenziato in questa [domanda](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425677/origin-of-the-saying-happy-wife-happy-life) il modo di dire “*happy wife, happy life*” è abbastanza comune nella lingua inglese.  Il significato è molto intuitivo e mi chiedevo se esiste un’espressione equivalente in italiano.

Io non riesco trovarne e l’unico proverbio che mi viene in mente che riguarda la vita coniugale è “[tra moglie  e marito non mettere il dito](http://www.scuolissima.com/2015/09/tra-moglie-e-marito-non-mettere-il-dito.html)” il cui significato è molto diverso.

Qualcuno conosce un modo di dire simile a quello inglese?

Comment: Per quello che vale, nel mio angolo del mondo anglofono, questa espressione è rarissima.

Answer (score 4):

Nel *Dizionario comparato di proverbi e modi proverbiali* di Augusto Arthaber (non esattamente recentissimo), tra i proverbi su “moglie”, ce ne sono due che si avvicinano:

> Senza moglie a lato, l'uom non è beato

che non contiene il concetto della “happy wife”, ma ha dalla sua anche un richiamo all'Ariosto: “Senza moglie a lato / Non puote uomo in bontate esser perfetto” (*Sat.* VI).

L'altro è:

> Chi ha moglie cattiva allato, è sempre travagliato.

che fa anche riferimento al carattere della moglie.

Comment: Non sono di uso comune, ma il senso nel primo caso è vicino a quello  inglese.

Answer (score 0):

Con un po' di malizia si potrebbe interpretare:
"La donna felice non si lagna"

In un libro di proverbi toscani ho letto questo:

"Pere e donne senza romori sono stimate le migliori"

(Proverbi toscani di Fortunato Bellonzi, Giunti)

Comment: Sei lo stesso che ha risposto a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9000/707)? Se volessi unificare i tuoi account, nel "Help Center" si spiega quello che devi fare: "visit the [contact form](http://italian.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’."

Comment: Interessante, ma nel detto inglese il senso è che  quando  la  moglie  è felice, è felice anche il marito e quindi la vita coniugale.  Come dire che il perno attorno a cui gira la serenità della vita coniugale è la moglie.

Comment: “Se vuoi” o “se volessi”, @Charo!

Comment: Grazie, @DaG, ho corretto!